# How to estimate the importance of a query for a particular document?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, information-retrieval

I have a two lists of words:

```
q = ['hi', 'how', 'are', 'you']

doc1 = ['hi', 'there', 'guys']

doc2 = ['how', 'is', 'it', 'going']
```

Is there any way of calculate the "relevance" or imporance score between `q` and `doc1` and `doc2`? My intuition tells me I can do this through IDF. Therefore, this is an implementation for idf:

```
def IDF(term,allDocs):
    docsWithTheTerm = 0
     for doc in allDocs:
            if term.lower() in allDocs[doc].lower().split():
                docsWithTheTerm = docsWithTheTerm + 1
            if docsWithTheTerm > 0:
                return 1.0 + log(float(len(allDocs)) / docsWithTheTerm)
            else:
                return 1.0
```

However, this doesnt give me itself something like a "relevance score". Is IDF the correct way of getting a relevance score? In the case of IDF is the incorrect way of measuring the importance of a query given a document how can I get something like a "relevance score"?

Answer (score 1):

The premise of using tf-idf is to place emphasis on rarer words that appear in the text: the premise being that focusing on overly common words will not allow one to determine which words are meaningful and which are not.

In your example, here is how you could implement tf-idf in Python:

```
doc1 = ['hi', 'there', 'guys']
doc2 = ['how', 'is', 'it', 'going']
doc1=str(doc1)
doc2=str(doc2)

stringdata=doc1+doc2
stringdata

import re
text2=re.sub('[^A-Za-z]+', ' ', stringdata)

from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
print(word_tokenize(text2))
text3=word_tokenize(text2)
```

The words have been tokenized and appear as follows:

```
['hi', 'there', 'guys', 'how', 'is', 'it', 'going']
```

Then, a matrix is generated:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(text3).todense()
```

This is the matrix output:

```
matrix([[0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

However, to make sense of this matrix, we now wish to store as a pandas dataframe, with word frequency in ascending order:

```
import pandas as pd

# transform the matrix to a pandas df
matrix = pd.DataFrame(matrix, columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names())
# sum over each document (axis=0)
top_words = matrix.sum(axis=0).sort_values(ascending=True)
```

Here is what we come up with:

```
going    1.0
guys     1.0
hi       1.0
how      1.0
is       1.0
it       1.0
there    1.0
dtype: float64
```

In this example, there is little context to the words - all three sentences are common introductions. Therefore, tf-idf won't necessarily reveal anything meaningful here, but in the context of a text with 1000+ words for example, tf-idf can be quite useful in terms of determining importance across words. e.g. you might decide that words appearing between 20-100 times in the text are rare - yet commonly occurring enough to merit importance.

In this particular case, one could potentially obtain a relevance score by determining how many times the words in the query appear in the relevant documents - specifically the words that tf-idf have flagged as important.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you have to represent the words as numbers somehow so you can do arithmetic on them to find "similarity". TF-IDF is one such way and Michael Grogan's answer should get you started there.

Another way is to use a pretrained Word2Vec or GloVe model. These word embedding models map words to a set of numbers which represent the semantic meaning of the word.

Libraries such as Gensim would allow you to very easily use pretrained embedding models to measure similarity. See here: https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim-data

===

Edit: For more advanced word embeddings, checkout ELMo or BERT